# .NET RegEx: Capture Date Group of varying formats and ignore year if repeated

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I do have a pattern of software names and release dates in a list.

```
Software Name 2020 20200506
Software Various Name 2020-05-06
Software Name 2020/07/10 2020 Edition
Software New Name 24.12.2019 2019 Edition
Software New Name 102020 2019 Edition
Software New Name 09-2019 2019 Edition
```

I am trying to create a .NET RegEx which will capture only the release date so that I run normalization replacement patterns via RegEx.

My current code is unable to tell apart between software edition year and date.

```
(?=.*?(20[012]\d)?)(20[012]\d\W?\d{1,2}\W?(\d{1,2})?) \m\i
```

is unable to ignore the year part before or behind the date. You may see the results by clicking the link:

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/KNilEY/1)

I know I am missing some logic here, but since my regex skills are still at a beginner level, I was hoping someone could assist me refining my regex so it does recognize the date without capturing the year before or after it.

Thanks

Comment: `\d{4}([-/.]?)\d{2}(?:\1\d{2})?|\d{2}([-/.]?)(?:\d{2}\2)?\d{4}` like [this](https://regex101.com/r/KNilEY/2)?

Comment: There are different date formats in here. `\b(?:\d{4}([^\w\s]?)\d{2}\1\d{2}|\d{2}([^\w\s]?)\d{2}\2\d{4}|\d{2}[^\w\s]?\d{4})\b` will also do, probably

Comment: Dear ctwheels and Wiktor Stribiżew thank you for your input. I really appreciate the time you took. Both your solutions did provide some insight on how to simplify things a little bit more and have the right capture group. I am a little bit perplexed in regard to the use of the non-capture (?:). Is there any chance someone could explain to me what exactly is the non-capture group's function here. Thank you so much.